# NoSuchMethodError com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity

Tags: java, intellij-idea, orientdb

I am running a Java test program to establish a connection to OrientDB and keep getting these exceptions when I run the code from within IntelliJ IDEA or OpenFire (xmpp server):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.(OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.java:43)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.(OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.java:48)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OSBTreeCollectionManagerRemote.(OSBTreeCollectionManagerRemote.java:58)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379) at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$2.call(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2863)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$2.call(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2854)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:64)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageAbstract.getResource(OStorageAbstract.java:143)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.getResource(OStorageRemoteThread.java:658)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.initAtFirstOpen(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2853)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:260)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcConnection.(OrientJdbcConnection.java:63)
>   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver.connect(OrientJdbcDriver.java:52)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187) at
>   com.momentum.orientdb.core.JdbcConnectionManager.getConnection(JdbcConnectionManager.java:87)
>   at
>   com.momentum.orientdb.core.JdbcConnectionManager.getConnection(JdbcConnectionManager.java:56)
>   at
>   com.momentum.orientdb.core.JdbcConnectionManager$getConnection.call(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>   at
>   com.momentum.orientdb.core.test.JdbcConnectionManagerTest.testGetConnection(JdbcConnectionManagerTest.groovy:26)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160) at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

**Any idea why? How can I fix it?**

**UPDATE 1**

It seems to me that it has to do with this library (from Google): **concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.1.jar**.

But I searched the development computer's file system and found only the above mentioned version (1.4.1).

**UPDATE 2 - Solution**

After searching thoroughly I found that I had different version of  **concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-xxxx.jar** on my development machine's file system and somehow I "managed" to put two different versions in the build.

Meanwhile, I still get the same exceptions when using my library (which I've already tested) in order to establish a connection to OrientDb from within OpenFire since OpenFire uses another version of concurrentlinkedhashmap then the one being used by OrientDb (concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.1.jar).

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of respected Jar files ?

Comment: Please check the libraries where this code came from com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder?

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501506/dependency-trouble-using-cassandraunit-with-astyanax

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchMethodError` happens because at runtime, Java tried to call a method on an object, and found it didn't exist, in particular:

```
com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;
```

Of course, you'd expect the code wouldn't compile if that was the case, so this almost always means you've built against a different version of the class than the one provided at runtime - it's usually a versioning issue.

So, you should figure out which library you're getting `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` from, and compare this with the version being used at runtime (how are you deploying this?  Is it running straight from IntelliJ?).  You're likely to find that they have different versions, and you'll need to alter your version to match.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the below link and download the JAR file,

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4.2

The problem is with the version which you are trying, the correct version is 1.4.2.